# How to transpile ES6 imports in Chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs

I am using the least minimal setup for a react application:

- Webpack
- Babel
- React + Flux
- Mocha & Chai for testing

I want to test my app now.

I have a .babelrc with the following content:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "ignore": false
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import AppStore from '../src/js/stores/app-store';

describe('app store', () => {
  assert.equal(3,3);
});
```

**When I comment the second import out, it works.**

When I import my AppStore, I am getting this error message:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { dispatch, register } from '../dispatchers/app-dispatcher';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

So, I am apparently transpiling the test.js file, **but the imports won't transpile to ES5.**

> What can I do, how does a minimal setup look like (without using Grunt
>   or whatever).

EDIT: My node scripts inside the package.json look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack && webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"
  },
```

Comment: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive` should be `mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive`. Depending on different versions ofc.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same issue. Having tried every other solution on stackoverflow and beyond, this simple config on package.json did it for me:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
```

All my ES6 imports worked after that.
By the way, I had this same configuration inside webpack.config.js, but apparently this was the only way to make it work for mocha testing as well.